# Printing (Cocoa) WebView contents results in cut images

Tags: html, cocoa, image, webview

Is there any way to avoid the rendered HTML elements in a `WebView` from being cut when printing?

This is a sample of what I'm trying to avoid:

[image: WebView image rendered in webview, cut when printed]

I'm printing to PDF using the following code:

```
// Copy the NSPrintInfo's sharedPrintInfo dictionary to start off with sensible defaults
NSDictionary* defaultValues = [[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo] dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary* printInfoDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:defaultValues];

// Set the target destination for the file
[printInfoDictionary setObject:[savePanel URL] forKey:NSPrintJobSavingURL];

// Create the print NSPrintInfo instance and change a couple of values
NSPrintInfo* printInfo = [[[NSPrintInfo alloc] initWithDictionary: printInfoDictionary] autorelease];
[printInfo setJobDisposition:NSPrintSaveJob];
[printInfo setRightMargin:30.0];
[printInfo setLeftMargin:30.0];
[printInfo setTopMargin:70.0];
[printInfo setBottomMargin:70.0];
[printInfo setHorizontalPagination: NSFitPagination];
[printInfo setVerticalPagination: NSAutoPagination];
[printInfo setVerticallyCentered:NO];
[printInfo setHorizontallyCentered:NO];

// Create the print operation and fire it up, hiding both print and progress panels
NSPrintOperation* printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:view printInfo:printInfo];
[printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
[printOperation setShowsProgressPanel:NO];
[printOperation runOperation];
```

Comment: I remember that there was something you could do in the CSS that could (at least in theory, if it's implemented in relevant versions of WebKit) influence the renderer toward solving this, but I don't remember enough to write up a full answer. Sorry.

Comment: There's `page-break-before`, `page-break-inside` and `page-break-after` but sadly, only Opera supports `-inside` and while Safari does support `-before` and `-after`, it doesn't support the value `avoid` for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly likely that the problem there is in the CSS you're using to render the webview. Just make sure you're not using any container divs with "position: fixed".